# Can I create link to a page in the home screen?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen, app-widgets, home-screen-folders

I'd like to have several collections of apps but also widgets. Problem is widgets can't be in folders.
But, could I just link to another page of the home screen? Thus each page would be my unit of organization. But I could access all of them from page 0 without scrolling N times.
Is it possible in some way?

Comment: There's no standard for home screen apps, so it depends if they support it or not...

Comment: Home screen and how the icons are organized there is managed by the selected launcher app. You can install other launcher apps that can have a totally different UI and usage concept see e.g. https://devsjournal.com/top-weird-unusual-launchers-to-transform-your-android-phone-interface.html